# Access Postgres Logs on Azure RDS flexible-server through Azure CLI

Tags: azure, logging, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

Is there a way to access (optimally "output" otherwise download) postgres logs on a Azure RDS flexible-server? The issue is we have a customer that is reluctant to use the queries of the logs in the azure portal so we would like to offer him access through the Azure CLI tools. So far I didn't find any way how to do this though, als no options for accessing the logs through the AZ CLI here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/postgres/flexible-server?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 0):

> So far I didn't find any way how to do this though, als no options for
> accessing the logs through the AZ CLI

***Currently its not available for flexible server to fetch the logs as listed on the*** [***MS DOC***](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/postgres/flexible-server?view=azure-cli-latest)

Using Azure CLI, we can access Postgres logs on Azure server by using below `cmdlets`:-

***To list the logs for your server use:-***

```
az postgres server-logs list --resource-group myresourcegroup --server mydemoserver > log_files_list.txt
```

***To download individually log files for your server use :-***

```
az postgres server-logs download --name 20170414-mydemoserver-postgresql.log --resource-group myresourcegroup --server mydemoserver
```

For more information Please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***Configure and access server logs by using Azure CLI***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-configure-server-logs-using-cli) , [***`az postgres server-logs`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/postgres/server-logs?view=azure-cli-latest) & [***Configure and Access Logs in Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/howto-configure-and-access-logs)

Comment: I tried those CMDs before but I get: `ERROR: (ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/[name]' under resource group 'yyy' was not found.` I made sure i use the correct server name and resource group. In the JSON view of the server I see "/subscriptions/[subscription-id]/resourceGroups/[resource-group]/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/[name]" I guess this is just available for "normal" servers (not flexible) since the cmd looks for "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/[name]" while the ID states "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/[xxx]"

Comment: Please refer this Workaround as mentioned in this [**MS Q&A**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/748780/error-running-the-code-on-bash-window-on-azure-for.html) for similar issue .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Flexible Server this is not possible, as it uses drastically different logging system from the Single Server product. You will need to enable "Diagnostic Settings" to send the type of logs you are interested in to Log Analytics Workspace. This is a built in behaviour, and will offer you to create a new Workspace automatically during setup. It is also possible to automate this either via CLI or Terraform etc.

You will then be able to use AZ CLI, to query the logs. See docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-log-analytics-query

Example Cli command to query all latest errors from the logs would be:

> az monitor log-analytics query -w workspace-name --analytics-query
> "AzureActivity | where Message contains "error""